# Adding the "Select all" option to a drop down list in html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the "Select All" option to my drop down list so that i can select all the values in dropdown list by a single click on "Select All" option.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, this is not possible using only `HTML`. You need `JavaScript` for this.

Comment: You could add a checkbox in the form named "Select All" and you will have an accessable solution, although the question doesn't mention anything like that, I always like non-JS solutions if possible

Comment: OK..give me solution in javascript

Comment: @user2118527 It doesn't work that way here on stackoverflow, you first have to show you've tried finding a solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.here it is...

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script language="javascript">
      function changeSelection(value){

      var length = document.getElementById("ch").options.length;

      if(value == 0){
      for(var i = 1;i<length;i++)
        document.getElementById("ch").options[i].selected = "selected";

      document.getElementById("ch").options[0].selected = "";
      }

  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select multiple onchange="changeSelection(this.value)"
     id="ch">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">C</option>
<option value="2">C++</option>
<option value="3">Java</option>
<option value="4">SQL</option>
<option value="5">HTML</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```